# How to display attached values as selected in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm using many to many relationship in laravel 8. Have two models: Room and Service.
I have attached some services to a specific room and now, when I want to edit this specific room I need it to show me which services are selected and which are not.

This is a code I am using:

```
<select class="form-select" name="service_id[]" id="service_id" multiple>
    @foreach($services as $service)
    <option value="{{ $service->id }}" @if($rooms->services->in_array()) selected @endif>{{ $service->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```php
@if(in_array($service->id, $rooms->services->pluck('id')->toArray(), true)) selected @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at your controller:

```
$RoomServicesIds = [];
foreach($room->services as $service ){
 array_push($RoomServicesIds ,$service->id);
}
```

Then return `$RoomServicesIds` variable with your blade file

In your blade file change the condition to that one:

```
@if(in_array($service->id,$RoomServicesIds)) selected @endif
```